# Properties of symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, bilinear-form

Given a symmetric bilinear form, I have not yet understood how one can find:

- whether the BLF is **positiv-definite**
- the **signature** without calculating eigenvalues etc..
- check if the BLF is **degenerate** or not
- get an **orthogonal basis** for this BLF

Although I understand the concepts in theory, I would like to figure out a way to do the computations. Is there such an algorithm? From what I have seen, one can do the following to get the signature:

- reduce the matrix ($M$) that represents the BLF to a diagonal form and apply the same row and column operations to the standard matrix ($E$). When $M$ is in diagonal form, one can then easily read the signature from the diagonal entries.

Is there a name for this technique? How could I use this technique to check if the BLF is positiv definit and degenerate? I can't find any clear information about these topics. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, as I have been struggling for days with these topics.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr     This is sometimes taught  without indicating the extra matrices I like to put, which are  my $E_j$  each for an elementary operation

Comment: I think you would like http://www.astronomia.edu.uy/progs/algebra/Linear_Algebra,_4th_Edition__(2009)Lipschutz-Lipson.pdf    The algorithm I  use (well, programmed for integer symmetric matrices  is in Section 12.5, pages 361-362,  called Algorithm 12.1 (Congruence Diagonalization of a symmetric matrix).   Also labelled pdf (367, 368) out of 432....  Not sure why they did this, Example 12.2 Alright, jump to solved problem 12.8 on page 367-368, 12.9 on 368, Example 12.2 on page 362   is not the same thing, it is about something a bit different  called similarity, $P^{-1} H P = D$

Comment: @WillJagy Okay, thank you so much for your time! I will dig into the links you sent me!

Comment: @WillJagy ok got the basics down now. So here is another question that came up: Let's say that I have the matrix of a symmetric BLF and apply the congruence diagonalization process. From what I understand, now I can find the signature, the radical and whether it is degenerate or not, and conclude the same for the BLF (as it is congruent)? Can I now also find an orthogonal basis for the BLF? Are those the column vectors of $P$? Thank you again for the links - helped a ton! :)

Comment: Aris, in that case you should really tell me how and why you are studying this; details would include what book  of notes you are using ( a link) as well as whether you are in a class with lectures. If this is material requested by a computer science  class, for example, that would matter.  Maybe the most glaring problem: in a previous question (your comment following)  you mention Jordan form. People usually need help with this, but I have usually given answers with what I feel to be the easiest method when eigenvalues are all integers (as well as the matrix elements)

Comment: @WillJagy I am preparing for a Linear Algebra 2 exam in University and I am going through some old exams - that's where this question came from. I am studying computer science with a minor in mathematics. I do not ask for a solution to anything, I just want to get some intuition on those topics.